# Code after -(bool)someMethod not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very odd bug with my code. I have a method that saves a message to Parse.com. If the message saves I want run a method that increments a counter and returns a BOOL: `[self canIncrementMessageCountForUser:tempName];`. Code below:

```
 [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if(succeeded) {

            PFRelation *receivedMessages = [messageBank relationForKey:@"receivedMessages"];
            [receivedMessages addObject:message];


            [self canIncrementMessageCountForUser:tempName]; 
            [messageBank saveInBackground];
            NSLog(@"message send to %@",tempName);

        }

    }];//end block, this works
```

For some reason anything after the line `[self canIncrementMessageCountForUser:tempName];` isn't called. I have no idea why. It's driving me mad. Again canIncrementMessageCountForUser returns a bool. Any ideas what is going on here?

EDIT: added code for increment method:

```
-(BOOL)canIncrementMessageCountForUser: (NSString *)user {

    //erase the dictionary if it's a new day
    [self flushDictionaryIfNeeded];

    //load up a dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);



    //if empty it's a yes
    if([dictionary count]==0){
        NSLog(@"empty dictionary");
        NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user];
        [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return YES;

    }

    //if it's not empty it's only a yes if the key doesn't exist
    else {

        //not in dict so unique
        if(![dictionary objectForKey:user]){
            NSLog(@"username we are checking is: %@",user);
            NSLog(@"First message for %@ today!",user);
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            [dictionary setObject:now forKey:user]; 
            [defaults setObject:dictionary forKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            return YES;

        }


        else {

            NSLog(@"Already messaged %@ today!",user);
            return NO;



        }




    }


}
```

Basically this method returns true if the user hasn't been messaged today by checking a key (the same as the user string passed in).

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to step through your code?

Comment: why do you even call that function if you throw away its return value immediately?

Comment: I will actually use that value...this is just temp for testing.

Comment: What values have inside de tempName?

Comment: What's the code behind `canIncrementMessageCountForUser:`?

Comment: OK so you are certain that this method returns something? If so what about `saveInBackground` do you make it into this method?

Comment: The code doesn't call [messageBank saveInBackground]. I tested a few other things. It won't call anything after [self canIncrementMessageCountForUser:tempName]; If this method doesn't return a BOOL will it cause a problem? I checked the logic in it, seems like all bases are covered...

Comment: Are any of your `NSLog` statements in `canIncrement...` being hit?

Answer (score 0):

Want to post this incase someone else finds it useful. I figured out the problem it was in this block:

```
//load up a dictionary
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary allKeys]);
```

Need **NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[defaults objectForKey:@"uniqueSentToday"] mutableCopy];**. Even though you can write mutable objects to NSUserDefaults, if the object is read out it will be immutable so need to call the mutableCopy. Otherwise it will get stuck on **[dictionary setObject:now forKey:user];** and just not execute any other lines after it. Works fine now. I wonder why it would get completely stuck on that line and not execute any other lines thought or throw a compiler error..

Comment: I just tested this an get an exception as expected on `setObject:forKey:`